# jquery ajax soap call, not able to get response?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, soap

Please check the below code. Can any body point me what is wrong with this code?
Please also suggest me how i can trace error with this.

```
   <html>
    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css">
            <!-- jQuery and jQuery Mobile -->
            <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var webServiceURL = 'https://www.kaiz.co.za/tunnel-web/secure/axis/kaiz';
        var soapMessage='<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?><soapenv:Envelope\
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"\
        xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"\
        xmlns:urn="urn:http.eli.com"\
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"\
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">\
        <soapenv:Body><urn:getUserDetail><emailAddress>a@abc.com</emailAddress>\
        <password>a</password></urn:getUserDetail></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';



        function CallService()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: webServiceURL, 
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "xml", 
                data: soapMessage, 
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
                processData: false,
                success: OnSuccess, 
                error: OnError
            });

            return false;
        }

        function OnSuccess(data, status)
        {
            alert(data.d);
        }

        function OnError(request, status, error)
        {
            alert('error');
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery.support.cors = true;
        });
    </script>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="Call Web Service" onclick="CallService(); return false;" />
        </div>
    </form>
    </head>
    </html>
```

Comment: What's the current behavior? No alert, and no error message in the console?

Comment: What have you already tried while debugging?

Comment: I am newbie to js  and dont know how should i trace this

Comment: Open the javascript console. CTRL+SHIFT+K.

Comment: Did you do some basic research on how to perform debugging in javascript?

Comment: Here is the response object  readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error"

Comment: then I would expect either `OnSuccess` or `OnError` to be called. Note: I recommend naming functions with lowercase. Uppercase is for classes.

Comment: processData should be false, and your webservice looks like it might be cross-origin, so you'll have to make sure the webservice is implementing CORS if it is indeed cross-origin.

Comment: pls have look at the code. I have edited it with original url and data.

Comment: @KevinB have you look at the code?

Comment: I have now, but that doesn't help decide whether or not you are making a CORS request or whether or not the server is properly implementing CORS. I don't see anything wrong with the code above.

Comment: I am calling this webservice from browser and how can i know that server is properly implementing cors or not?

Comment: *"I am calling this webservice from browser "* what website is said browser on when said request is made? As far as CORS, if the browser isn't receiving the response and you're seeing a console error ACCESS DENIED in google chrome or firefox+firebug, then it is not implemented properly.